# Counting distinct items within a category on SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I need to compose a SQL statement as follows:

I have a table with many items, each item having a category. In total there are 3 categories.

I need to select the DISTINCT categories and then order them by number of items within each category.

Would this be a good way? Or too slow?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT category, count(*) AS counter
FROM item_descr
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` is not needed since you are using `GROUP BY category`:

```
SELECT category, count(*) AS counter
FROM item_descr
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

The `GROUP BY` is doing what you want. `DISTINCT` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to have an index on category if you want good performance especially on larger tables.

Comment: This statement is, in fact, probably not true, because the category has too few values for the index to be effective.

Comment: You don't know that.  What the user said was "I have a table with many items, each item having a category"  The table has many items but only 3 category options.  For all we know the table has 10 items or 10 million.  You cannot guess table size based on the cardinality of the category field in the table.  If you can use an index to effectively eliminate one third of a large database, it will help.

Comment: The issue with the index is about the number of categories, not the number of items.  Three categories means that the index is going to have very, very high selectivity.  It probably won't have much impact on performance.

Comment: I agree it may not have much impact but in some situations any boost you can get is a positive one especially if you need to consider user perception of speed.